# Unable to change z index within ItemsControl WPF

Tags: wpf, z-index, itemscontrol

I want to dynamically change the z-index of my lines when I click on them, but haven't found any success so far.

Here is my XAML where I'm simply binding to a list of track view models, and then a list of line coordinates within each view model:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CircuitTracks}">

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!-- Bind onto List of LineCoords in each CircuitTracks object -->
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding LineCoords}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <Canvas ZIndex="{Binding ZIndex}"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <!-- For each LineCoord object, draw out a line with coordinates. Currently bound to LineCoord object. 1 Ancestor level up is List of Line Coords, 2 Levels up is LDLTrack Object -->
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Canvas>
                            <Line  X1="{Binding X1, Converter={StaticResource ScaleXCoordConverter}}" Y1="{Binding Y1, Converter={StaticResource ScaleYCoordConverter}}"
                                   X2="{Binding X2, Converter={StaticResource ScaleXCoordConverter}}" Y2="{Binding Y2, Converter={StaticResource ScaleYCoordConverter}}"
                                   Stroke="{Binding DataContext.LineColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentPresenter, AncestorLevel=2}}" 
                                   StrokeThickness="2" StrokeEndLineCap="Flat" StrokeStartLineCap="Flat">
                                <Line.InputBindings>
                                    <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftClick" Command="{Binding DataContext.OccupyTrackCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentPresenter, AncestorLevel=2}}"/>
                                </Line.InputBindings>

                            </Line>

                        </Canvas>
                    </DataTemplate>

                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                        <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="{Binding ZIndex}"/>
                    </Style>
                </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>

            </ItemsControl>


        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

</ItemsControl>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofCz1.jpg

As you can see here, when I click a track the track currently turns red, via a command. Within the command I've also changed an integer ZIndex to a higher value, and this property is bound to my XAML.

Here's my view model code:

```
public class CircuitTrackViewModel : BaseViewModel {

        public CircuitTrackViewModel(TrackCircuit trackCircuit) {
            TrackCircuit = trackCircuit;
            LineCoords = new ObservableCollection<LineCoordinates>();
            ConvertMSection();

        }

        private TrackCircuit _trackCircuit;

        public TrackCircuit TrackCircuit {
            get => _trackCircuit;
            set {
                _trackCircuit = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("TrackCircuit");
            }

        }
        private ICommand _occupyTrackCommand;
        public ICommand OccupyTrackCommand => _occupyTrackCommand =
            _occupyTrackCommand ?? new DelegateCommand(ChangeColor);

        private string _lineColor = "DimGray";
        public string LineColor {
            get => _lineColor;
            set {
                if (_lineColor == value)
                    return;
                _lineColor = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("LineColor");
            }
        }

        private int _zIndex;

        public int ZIndex {
            get => _zIndex;
            set {
                if (_zIndex == value)
                    return;
                _zIndex = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ZIndex");
            }
        }

        public void ChangeColor() {
            LineColor = LineColor == "DimGray" ? "Red" : "DimGray";
            ZIndex = ZIndex == 0 ? 100 : 0;
        }

        public ObservableCollection<LineCoordinates> LineCoords { get; set; }
```

What I want to happen is when you click the track, the Z index is updated and the track is essentially re-rendered to sit on top of the track next to it, so there's no grey covering the red at all. Is this possible by altering my code in some way? Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: The ItemContainerStyle should be dclared for the outer ItemsControl.

Comment: I've tried setting it in both inner and outer ItemsControl with no luck unfortunately. @Clemens

Comment: Of course the outer ItemsControl would also need to use a Canvas as ItemsPanel.

Comment: You may perhaps also replace the inner ItemsControl with a simple Polyline.

Comment: I added an ItemsPanel Canvas to the outer ItemsControl as you said and it doesn't seem to have affected anything @Clemens

Comment: Unfortunately it has to be a Line in this project @Clemens